# Non-numeric characters inside regular expression's curly braces

Tags: regex

Curly braces are useful to specify a specific amount of repetition in regular expressions.

However, I've just see the following regular expression: `[\t\p{Zs}]`.

Is it correct to put non-numeric characters between curly braces? If so, what operation is it?

What is the significance of the fact that the curly braces appear in the square brackets?

Comment: what's the name of the Regular Expression Engine you're using?

Comment: @Kira It's irrelevant; I saw the above in the web..

Comment: No, it's extremely relevant I'm afraid. The above regular expression it's not portable across regular expression engines. For clarity sakes, try the following code in Python `re.findall(b'[\t\p{Zs}]', b'Zsp')` and this other in Ruby `"Zsp".scan /[\t\p{Zs}]/`

Comment: It's not an expression I've used but I saw it online - I did not know what engine is suitable. The engine which I use isn't related to this expression and therefore irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\p{Zs}` is a [POSIX bracket expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class) and is equivalent to a character class, much like `\s` is a character class for `[\v\r\n\t\f ]`

`\p{Zs}` now refers to a space character, as you can see in the link I referred to above.

Comment: Thanks for the link. By the way, `\p` can't come without following braces?

Comment: @Reflection Sorry for the late reply. I somehow didn't get notified =/. Without the braces, `\p` becomes the literal `p` character.

Answer (score 0):

This regex:

```
[\t\p{Zs}]
```

Matches any one of the following:

- `\t` - tab character
- `\p{Zs}` a whitespace character that is invisible